# Azure and Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have several azure websites that I would like to manage via Visual Studio but I am having problems accessing the right folders.

I have successfully added my azure details to Visual Studio and can see my websites listed, if I expand I can see a Files folder, however this folder does not contain my website code.

If I FTP to this azure website, I can see that VS is only showing me the contents of wwwroot, my website code is in a different folder.  How do I configure VS to show files save in different Azure folders?

[image: Visual Studio Azure screenshot]

As you can see the files folder shows me what is in wwwroot, but my website code is in another folder.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what Visual Studio shows?

Comment: The website's code should be in the `wwwroot` folder